# Сохранить поле id с ассоциированным пользователем в Django

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

```
class Drummer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата рождения', blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата смерти',
                                     blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    bio = models.TextField(verbose_name='Информация')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, verbose_name='Фотография')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, db_index=True, null=True, unique=True, verbose_name='URL')
    group_name = models.ManyToManyField('Group', verbose_name='Группа')
    users_drummer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
```

У меня есть модель `Drummer`, которую я описал выше ☝️ с полем

```
users_drummer =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

В шаблоне я позволяю пользователю редактировать только те записи, которые создавались конкретным пользователем.

```
 {% if request.user.id == person.users_drummer.pk %}
         редактировать
```

Проблема в том, что когда я сохраняю форму от пользователя, то поле
`users_drummer` сохраняет в базу данных пустое поле (`null`), а мне нужно, чтобы когда пользователь вводил все поля формы в базу данных, поле `users_drummer` сохранялось с ассоциированным с пользователем (`user_id`). Поле `users_drummer` я не вывожу в форме, потому что это поле пользователь не должен видеть. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при заполнении пользователем формы, она сохранялась в базу данных с полем `users_drummer` ассоциированным с конкретным пользователем?
Форма:

```
class AddDrummerForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
        model = Drummer
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death',
                  'bio', 'photo', 'slug')
```

view:

```
class AddView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddDrummerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('drummers:home')
    template_name = 'drummers/add_drummer.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Добавление барабанщика'
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял суть задачи, то можно либо через переопределение метода save() формы:

```
class AddDrummerForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def save(self, request, commit=True):
    drummer = super().save(commit=False)
    drummer.users_drummer = request.user
    if commit:
      drummer.save()
    return drummer
  class Meta:
    model = Drummer
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 
              'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death',
              'bio', 'photo', 'slug')
```

либо создать скрытое поле формы users_drummer и в шаблоне уже присвоить ему нужное значение

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Просто проблема в том, что request не определен в файле forms.py как мне передать объект request методу save?

Comment: А как реализован контролер?

Comment: ```
class AddView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddDrummerForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('drummers:home')
    template_name = 'drummers/add_drummer.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Добавление барабанщика'
        return context
```

Comment: Давай отвечу чуть позже, не за ПК сейчас просто.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Привет, соряй что долго, день насыщенный выдался. По вопросу: в классе AddView переопредели функцию form_valid. def form_valid(self, form): self.object = form.save(self.request) return super().form_valid(form)

Comment: лучше наверное так сделать [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HaUVCfZM) чтоб не пихать полностью request

Comment: спасибо еще раз за помощь!
ругается на метод form_valid во воьюхах, пишет:
1)save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
2) Instance attribute object defined outside __init__    пишет на self.object
3) Signature of method 'AddDrummerForm.save()' does not match signature of the base method in class 'BaseModelForm' пишет в forms в классе AddDrummerForm

Comment: у тебя discord или telegram есть?

Comment: да, телега есть.
Как тебя там найти?

Comment: (https://t.me/@masquarade00)